# Value from inside for loop overwriting data outside loop

Tags: javascript, closures, leaflet

Everytime I run this loop, each marker in the markers array has it's icon overwritten by the results from `let icon = iconLoader.getIcon(data[index][5]);`.
leaving each marker having the last loaded icon, instead of the icon loading during each pass of the for loop.

I thought that passing icon into the closure would essentially pass it by value, preventing it from being overwritten outside the scope of the closure, but this doesn't seem to be working for me. What am I missing?

```
var markers = []   
for (var index in data) {    
    let icon = iconLoader.getIcon(data[index][5]);
    var createMarker = (function (i) {  
        return function () {
            var marker = new L.marker([data[index][2], data[index][3]])
                .setIcon(i)    
            markers.push(marker);
        }
    })(icon);
    createMarker();
}

var iconLoader = (function () {   
    var icon = L.icon({
        // options
    });    
    return {
        getIcon: function (iconName) {
            // do stuff to get icon
            return icon;
        }
    };
}());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnzN2/748/)

Comment: Objects and arrays are always passed by reference unless you create a copy

Comment: You are also never invoking the function returned by your IIFE..at least not in the code you have provided, anyway.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the `setIcon` function? And preferably the structure of the marker class as well?

Comment: SetIcon and the Marker class are part of the leaflet library. [Code is here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/marker/Marker.js)

Comment: I also think you're right about the function not even getting called in that example. I've edited the code to actually call it. Same problem still though.

Comment: All you needed to do was add `()` after `(icon)` and it would have invoked it. Either way, though, I have tried and tried and have been unable to reproduce your error. Could you try to create a demo? This is what i've come up with, but it seems to work fine https://repl.it/GNPP

Comment: Looking at your example, it looks like it's working fine. I've modified the post with a fiddle that also has the issue I'm having. Both markers have the same icon, even though it's loading markers with different icons into the array, but the second one is overwriting the first.

Comment: Check and see if my solution works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I mentioned in my original comment, JavaScript objects and arrays are always passed by reference unless you explicitly create and pass a copy. Nothing in your code is inherently wrong and is not causing this issue - it is actually an issue with how leaflet is handling the object references internally. The way to avoid this is to do a **deep copy** on the result from `iconLoader.getIcon()`. If you are using jQuery, you can do it very simply by using `$.extend()`.

```
for (var index in data) {
  let icon = $.extend(true, {}, iconLoader.getIcon(data[index][2]));
  var marker = new L.marker([data[index][0], data[index][1]])
  .setIcon(icon);     
  markers.push(marker);
}
```

If not, you can look into non-jQuery solutions - it's not ideal, but they're everywhere.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was typing this up as mhodges was writing his answer. I'll go ahead and post it as it's a different solution that also solved the issue for me.

After looking at mhodges' working demo, I noticed he had set up the iconloader a bit differently than I had. He had the iconloader as an object...

```
var iconLoader = {
    getIcon: function (elem) {
        return elem;
    }
 }
```

while mine was set up as a closure...

```
var iconLoader = (function () {   
    var icon = L.icon({
        // options
    });    
    return {
        getIcon: function (iconName) {
            // do stuff to get icon
            return icon;
        }
    };
}());
```

I thought that maybe I could try setting it up a bit differently and see if that made a difference, and VOILA!

```
const proto = {
        getIcon (iconName) {
            var icon = L.icon({
                // options
            });   
            // do stuff to get icon
            return icon;
        }
    };

function factoryIcon() {
    return Object.create(proto);
}
```

and then grabbed the icon with

```
const iconFactory = factoryIcon();
let icon = iconFactory.getIcon(data[index][5]);
```